# Parametros invalidos de SQL

Tags: php, sql

Tengo un problema al consultar.

Me estoy basando a un curso, pero no quiere jalar los datos igual.

Me arroja este error

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\almacen\modelos\sucursales.modelo.php:81 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\almacen\modelos\sucursales.modelo.php(81): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\almacen\controladores\inventario.controlador.php(119): ModeloSucursales::mdlMostrarSucursalesPorProducto('sucursal', NULL, NULL, 1) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\almacen\views\inventario.php(73): ControladorInventario::ctrMostrarSucursalesPorProducto(NULL, NULL, 1) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\almacen\modelos\sucursales.modelo.php on line 81

Mis consultas son así:

```
$sucursales = $IDSucursal;
$item = null;
$valor = null;
$NombreSucursales = ControladorInventario::ctrMostrarSucursalesPorProducto($item, $valor, $sucursales); //Linea 73
foreach ($NombreSucursales as $key => $value) {
$NombreSucursal = $value["Sucursal"];
```

El controlador es

```
/*=============================================
   MOSTRAR CATEGORIAS POR USUARIO
   =============================================*/

   static public function ctrMostrarSucursalesPorProducto($item1, $valor, $sucursales)
   {
       $id = $sucursales;
       $tabla = "sucursal";

       $respuesta = ModeloSucursales::mdlMostrarSucursalesPorProducto($tabla, $item1, $valor, $id); //Linea 119

       return $respuesta;
   }
```

y este es el modelo

```
/*=============================================
    MOSTRAR SUCURSALES
    =============================================*/

    static public function mdlMostrarSucursalesPorProducto($tabla,$item, $valor, $id){

        if($id != null){

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE IDSucursal = :$id");

            $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetch(); //Linea 81

        }else{

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE IDSucursal = :$id");

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        }

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;

    }
```

Alguna sugerencia para poder hacer correr la consulta, estoy llevando el **idSucursal** desde otra consulta y quiero obtener el nombre de mi tabla sucursal para imprimirlo en lugar de su **id**.

La tabla sucursal tiene los campos: **IDSucursal** y **Sucursal**.

Answer (score 0):

Noto 2 errores en el `modelo`:

- En el `WHERE` ya estas pasando directamente el `id`.
- Estas pasando mal y demás los parámetros de `bindParam`.

Probá hacer lo siguiente:

```
$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE IDSucursal = :id");
$stmt-> bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

El método `bindParam` espera 4 parámetros:

1. El parámetro a remplazar, en este caso `:id`.
2. El valor, `$id` en este caso.
3. Tipo de dato, en este caso `PDO::PARAM_INT` (Por detrás esto es un simple ID).
4. Longitud que en este caso no la usamos.

En caso de más parámetros, tendrías que hacer más llamadas a `bindParam`.

Podes ver mas sobre el método acá [PDOStatement::bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en estas 3 líneas del modelo, separadas convenientemente para analizarlas

```php
static public function mdlMostrarSucursalesPorProducto($tabla,$item, $valor, $id){ //1

$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE IDSucursal = :$id"); //2

$stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, $id, PDO::PARAM_STR); //3
```

Si observas en 2da línea, estás tratando de enlazar un parámetro `:$id`, pero en `bindParam` se enlaza con otra variable `":$item"`, lo cual generará el mensaje de error que aparece.

Por otro lado, observar la [sintaxis de bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

```php
bindParam(':parametro', $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR, [longitud]);
```

En el código no se está respetando ese orden.

Finalmente, también puse la primera línea, la declaración del método estático, porque hay un argumento que está de más, y tengo 99% de certeza que es `$id`, ya que ese valor lo deberías estar mandando por la variable `$valor`.

Entonces esas 3 líneas deberían quedar así:

```php
static public function mdlMostrarSucursalesPorProducto($tabla, $item, $valor){

$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE IDSucursal = :$item");

$stmt -> bindParam(":$item", $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```